# How do I get this output to sort by date in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date field Datetime and I want a simple count of the items but i's like it in date order.. what I have now...

```
plot_data.Quradate.value_counts() # of respondents by survey date
2011-07-15    702
2011-04-15    696
2011-10-15    661
2010-01-15    636
2011-01-15    587
2010-10-15    570
2012-01-15    534
2010-07-15    525
2010-04-15    384
dtype: int64
```

Should be simple but not yet for me...

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) not work?

Comment: It is not the index... I tried plot_data=plot_data.sort(['Quradate']) before using the value counts, same result plot_data.Quradate.sort().value_counts() which says that This Series is a view of some other array, to sort in-place you must create a copy and then I try pdf=plot_data
pdf.Quradate.sort() which gives the same error This series....

Comment: Ugly, but gets the job done resp=pd.DataFrame(plot_data.Quradate.value_counts()) # of respondents by survey date
resp.sort_index()

Comment: Have you tried `plot_data.Quradate.value_counts().sort_index()`? I don't see why that wouldn't work.  It would help if you posted some sample data.

Answer (score 6):

As Andy points out And (+TomAugspurger above) this is the right solution:

```
plot_data.Quradate.value_counts().sort_index()
```

Ugly, but gets the job done would like to see a better solution.

```
resp=pd.DataFrame(plot_data.Quradate.value_counts()) # of respondents by survey date
resp.sort_index()
```

Comment: You don't need to make this a DataFrame, just plot_data.Quradate.value_counts().sort_index()

Comment: I suppose it's worth mentioning in 0.13 that you will be able to pass sort=False into value_counts (you already can in the top level one), obviously sorting once would be more efficient. :)

Comment: Whoa, saved me a ton of research! Thanks!